# Where could I find the FOD examples of C17?

Tags: jet-engine

I want to find some FOD examples of huge planes in reason of ground vortex,where should I  go to search?

Comment: What does "FOD examples" mean?

Comment: @CrossRoads Presumably, examples of incidents involving foreign object damage.

Comment: How does "Ground Vortex" come into play? A just departed plane would create a vortex that could drift down. ATC makes planes wait to depart behind one in order to give any vortex a chance to dissipate.

Comment: @CrossRoads I think they're referring to the vortex that forms on the ground towards the intakes. A Google image search for c17 ground vortex shows the phenomenon.

Comment: The NTSB search might bring something up still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search the National Traffic Safety Board here

https://www.ntsb.gov/_layouts/ntsb.aviation/index.aspx

as a starting point.

Under Aircraft:Category, select Airplane.

Under Model, Select C17.

Scroll down and select  Submit Query.

There are couple of hits on C17s on the first page of results, I didn't look at  further pages.

Try this stack exchange link also on the same occurrence, but not just limited to C17s.

[How does this vortex form inside a jet engine?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/21219/how-does-this-vortex-form-inside-a-jet-engine)