# What are these diagonal devices above the leading edge of the V-22 Osprey's wing?

Tags: feature-identification, v-22

The Osprey has some kind of aerodynamic devices sticking up along the top of the leading edge. This picture from [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_Boeing_V-22_Osprey) of the wings rotated shows them against its silhouette:-

[image: Osprey with wings folded]
Public domain picture taken by Lt. Col. Kevin Gross

You can see them a little clearer on this photo shot from above, on the same page:-

[image: Osprey in flight]
Author Peter Gronemann, licensed CC 2.0

Seen from above, they look like alternating slashes and backslashes, and they're clearly intended to change the flow properties in some way. But what precisely do they achieve, and how?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The protrusions you're asking about are vortex generators.

As to how they work, there is a separate Stack Exchange article on that: [How do vortex generators work?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/13876/what-is-a-vortex-generator)

(Please note, the linked question/answer does not even MENTION the CV-22, and is thus not a duplicate question to this one.)