# What is the "No Step" flap thingy used for on an A320 engine?

Tags: airbus-a320

There is a small plate sticking out of an A320's engine narcelle with "No Step" written on it. I tried taking a picture of it, which in retrospect didn't turn out as good as I wanted it to be, but I hope it helps:

[image]

Anyway, I'm wondering what it's used for? It's only on one side towards the aircrafts body and it seems to be too small to be an aerodynamic surface. I suspect it's used during maintenance?

Comment: does this answer your question? http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/11708/1467

Comment: @Federico It does indeed. I knew that must've been asked here before, I just had no idea what to enter besides "No step thingy". I also had no idea it was on other engines as well. I live in a small secluded world where all flights I take are on an A320 family plane.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a vortex generator explained in full in [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/13876/609)

"NO STEP" means don't put your foot on it. It's too weak to hold a person's weight and would get damaged.

Comment: Ah, that explains why I couldn't find anything when looking for this. Thanks :)

Comment: The person could also be damaged (though the mechanic who has to fix the bent metal doesn't really care about that - they're probably likely to inflict more damage on you for breaking their airplane).