# Aircraft wing stress design for 4 engine aircraft

Tags: wing

Can anyone tell me how aircraft wings are designed for mounting the engines. My area of self study is a typical engine on the A380 weighs 8000kgs and it’s weight is forward of the wing. As the wing stays the same angle of attack no matter whether the engine is installed, under power or at idle I cannot understand why there is no turning force on the wing. With this 8000kgs weight hanging out on the outboard engine where the wing is thinnest then why does it not have a twisting effect on the wing. I can understand how the wing can be stressed to allow for when an engine is installed but if you look at the wing profile it’s unchanged whether the engine is mounted or not.

Comment: Trust me, the wing **does** twist. But it needs to be stiff enough so the amount of twist is small. But all torsion moments are accounted for and the wing has a different twist distribution on the ground than in flight, because the loads change. [Here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/23375/how-do-you-choose-engine-placement-for-under-wings-engines/23382#23382) is some further reading.

Comment: Any load comes with deformation. Paraphrasing a professor from memory: "A large solid steel beam can only provide the force to support an ant walking on the end of the beam by bending. The only possible alternative is for the beam to break off."

Comment: I understand this but not why the wing does not twist by the overhang in front of the wing.